# Extract music metadata (music title, album title, artist name...) using react-player

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, rtmp, react-player

I'm building a simple web app that plays music streams.
The constitution of the web app is

audio.m4a -> ffmpeg -> nginx + rtmp module -> frontend browser

In the frontend browser, use [react-player](https://github.com/cookpete/react-player).
The audio data is published as HLS audio data.

So, I want to extract the metadata(music title, album title, artist name ...) from the data and display it in the browser. However, I could not find the way to that.
Anyone who knows this?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags

use javascript and this library, that read that all you want,

explore it! it works

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the library with react + react-player, but it didn't work. The `Can't resolve 'react-native-fs' in ... /node_modules/jsmediatags/build2` error occured. Do you have any idea?